# node.js, faye (bayeux) - after subscribe event

Tags: node.js, chat, real-time, faye, bayeux

I have a chat server. And after the clients subscribes I want to look in a DB to see if there is any history for the chat room they subscribed to.

The problem is, that I can only catch "subscribe" events in extension which must do "return callback(message);" to return the message. If I do the history thingy here nothing gets publishes to the clients because client isn't actually subscribed.

Is there any way to know when client ready? Or some event that happens on successfull subscription?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a callback after creating the subscription that will fire when you are successfully subscribed and another when you fail to subscribe:

```
var http = require('http');
var faye = require('faye');

var faye_server = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye', timeout: 120});

faye_server.listen(8089);

var subscription = faye_server.getClient().subscribe('/testing', function(message){console.log(message);});

subscription.callback(function(){console.log('Subscription successful and ready to use!');});

subscription.errback(function(){console.log('ERROR: Subscription failed!');});
```

This is documented on the faye mainpage although it's buried a bit. . . http://faye.jcoglan.com/browser/subscribing.html

This works on a node server, node client, or browser client as I've tested it.

Furthermore, what I have been doing to make sure my clients are up and running is this:  create client, then try to subscribe to garbage channel name.  Once that subscription comes up, fails, or times out (put 5 second time out around it) I take that as my client open success.  It's a bit of a round about method, but it's working very well for me and faye makes it pretty clean by using callback and errback just like in my previous example.

Now that's all on the client side, but it gets much easier on the server side:  http://faye.jcoglan.com/node/monitoring.html.  Just use the extensions here and look for subscribe events from specific clients and you are good to go.

Hope that helps